# Problem writing a telegram bot. It shows "Import "telegram.ext.updater" could not be resolved"

Tags: python, pip, bots, python-import, telegram-bot

[Import could not be resolved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BPOK.png)

I tried to install telegram-bot-python from Terminal many times, and also tried to install it from cmd, and nothing. Can someone help?
Ive literally tried almost anything and it pisses me off totally. Is Visual Studio the problem or have I written something wrong?

Comment: Some examples of what you have tried would be good. I'd also remove the profanity.

Answer (score 0):

You may be using **telegram** instead of **python-telegram-bot** so uninstall **telegram and python-telegram-bot** and reinstall only **python-telegram-bot**.

and check the changes in the documentation about updater

I hope it will help you.

[Link to Updater documentation](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Transition-guide-to-Version-20.0#updater)